# Is there another database server software for PHP other than MySQL?

Tags: linux, mysql, php, html, css

Is are there another database server software for PHP other than MySQL?

Does it run on Linux?

Does it work with Apache?

(No MySQL, can't get it working on ubuntu.)

Comment: Did you try installing apache with apt? try "sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1"

Answer (score 10):

Yes. There are hundreds, perhaps thousands of database servers available to you.

To be frank, if you haven't been successful in getting MySQL working on Ubuntu, you're either:

1. Reading really bad documentation
2. Reading good documentation but not understanding/executing properly
3. Giving up too soon

MySQL should be trivial to get running on Ubuntu. Quite honestly, ~30 seconds to install (and that's if you have a very slow internet connection), and perhaps 30 minutes to go through the steps of creating your first database and creating a user that has privileges on that db.

Other popular database server options are:

- PostgreSQL
- Oracle
- MongoDB
- Cassandra
- CouchDB
- SQLite

None of these (perhaps with the exception of SQLite, which isn't widely-supported) will be any easier to get running than MySQL.

Comment: I get errors, and I don't know where to start on fixing it. If you could help, that would be nice :)

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to completely re-work your question and include those errors then.

Comment: How did you go about installing mysql initially?  if needed, remove it and reinstall it through aptitude.

Comment: Given how hard it is to *not* get MySQL server working I'm betting on option 2.